# How to pass conditional attributes to template in Django ListView

Tags: django

I'm trying to make a list of employees that each day contains information ("today_note") if they are present at work or are sick.
I had no problem to do this in Flask, I simply rendered a template as below:

```
def employees_list():

    all_employees = Employee.query.order_by(Employee.name).all()

    today = date.today()

    for employee in all_employees:
        today_sick = db.session.query(SickLeave).filter(SickLeave.start_date <= today).filter(
        SickLeave.end_date >= today).filter(SickLeave.person_id == employee.id).all()

        if len(today_sick) != 0:
            employee.today_note = "C"
        else:
            employee.today_note = "✓"

    return render_template("employees_list.html", all_employees=all_employees)
```

and could access today_note for each employee in the template:

```
{% for employee in all_employees %}
{{ employee.today_note }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now I need to do the same in django. I can't figure out how to pass today_note to each instance of User model to be able to display it in the template.

```
class AllEmployeesList(ListView):

    template_name = "users/all_employees.html"
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'employees'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(AllEmployeesList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        all_employees = User.objects.all()

        today = date.today()


        for employee in all_employees:
            today_sick = Sickleave.objects.filter(Q(start_date__lte=today)&Q(end_date__gte= today)&Q(employee__id=employee.id)).all()
            if len(today_sick) != 0:
                employee.today_note = "C"
            else:
                employee.today_note = "✓"
  
        return context
```

I'm aware that here I completely miss reference to context

Edit: here are models

```
class Sickleave(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'Sickleave'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sickemployee', default=""
    )
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='C')
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField('Username', max_length=15, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last name', max_length=50)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)  
# (...)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    objects = UserManager()

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " "+ self.last_name
```

Comment: Can you provide the models?

Comment: you should override the [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) instead of get_context_data

Comment: After your for loop, add this line : `context['all_employees'] = all_employees`. To add the `all_employees` list to the context.

Comment: Thank you Rvector!!! Passing the context this way works perfectly fine

Comment: Give it please as an answer so I could accept it and close the question